# Extension methods resolution IQueryable vs IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a class which implements `IQueryable<>` (which inherits `IEnumerable<>`) interface.

When I call `Where()` method on it, compiler resolves this call to `IQueryable` extensions although `IEnumerable` extensions also has `Where()` method defined.

The question is how the compiler understands which extension should be called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

C# spec has it described:

> **7.5.3.5 Better conversion target**
>
> Given two different types `T1` and `T2`, `T1` is a better conversion target
>   than `T2` if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - **An implicit conversion from `T1` to `T2` exists, and no implicit conversion from `T2` to`T1` exists**
> - `T1` is a signed integral type and `T2` is an unsigned integral type.

Because there is a implicit conversion from `IQueryable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, and there is no implicit conversion from `IEnumerable<T>` to `IQueryable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>` is a better conversion target, and takes precedence.

Comment: Where is the implicit conversion defined between IQueryable<T> to IEnumerable<T>? I know that  IQueryable<T> inherits IEnumerable<T>. But implicit conversion to base class is not allowed.

Comment: @jannagy02 It most certainly *is* allowed.   `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant with respect to `T`.